# append text of System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, text, append

So, I thought this would be as simple as using the `AppendText` extension, but apparently the web form doesn't have it. So I wrote a method that does something similar:

```
private void AppendText(string s)
{
    textBox.Text = textBox.Text + s;
}
```

That works, but the box always scrolls back to the top when doing this. What are my options? I've Googled around and can't find a good answer...help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is due to postback of the page. its a normal behavior. you will have to manage client side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is the postback model of ASP.NET.  Essentially, the web page is "refreshing", showing your most current data.. this is all because the client has to send data back to the server, and then the server needs to return an "updated" version of the page back to the client.

Much like in the comments, one option is to manage via client side code.  If you are open to sticking to ASP.NET controls, I recommend using the "AJAX" UpdatePanel control - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb386454.aspx  It's typically pretty straightforward to add to a page with mostly declarative markup..

Hope this helps (and welcome to SO!)